# How to use the same image in multiple Customtkinter windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, widget, customtkinter

I'm building a GUI with Customtkinter and I've managed to display some sort of logo in a CTkLabel in the Main Window, using the PIL library. As I try to do the same in a Setup Window, it gives out an error.
The image in question is in the same directory as the file I'm working in.

The following code works, no problem whatsoever:

```
class MainWindow(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("700x400")

        self.img_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.img_frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill='x')

        self.logo = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("./logo.png"), size=(250, 80))
        print(self.logo)

        self.img_label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.img_frame, image= self.logo, compound="left", text="")
        self.img_label.grid(pady=10, padx=10, column=0, row=0, sticky="w")
```

I tried to mimmick this in the Setup Window iin the following way:

```
class SetupWindow(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.geometry("700x370")

        self.title_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self, height=100, width=680)
        self.title_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='news')

        self.logo = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("./logo.png"), size=(250, 80))
        print(self.logo)

        self.img = ctk.CTkLabel(self.title_frame, image= self.logo, compound="left", text="")
        self.img.grid(pady=10, padx=10, column=0, row=0, sticky="w")
```

It doesn't work. Gives out the following error message:

```
"Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
in __init__
    self.img = ctk.CTkLabel(self.title_frame, image= self.logo, compound="left", text="")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist"
```

Comment: You had this on module? `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

Comment: Yes, I have it. As I said, it works in the main window but not in the setup window...

Comment: Didn't you called `SetupWindow` from `MainWindow`?

Comment: Yes I did. The window itself runned fine until I tried the logo

Comment: One last question. Can you add parent to `ctk.CTkFrame(parent` in `SetupWindow` class?

Comment: You mean in the title_frame, name parent as master (instead of self)? If I do this, no error but also no frame appears in Setup window, istead, it creates a new frame in the main window (parent) with the logo visible.

Comment: How  did you called SetupWindow from MainWindow?

Comment: `def start_setup(self):
    setup_window = SetupWindow(self)
    self.withdraw()
    setup_window.mainloop()`

Comment: Well, after doing some research, Tkinter and customtkinter, take some exceptions when calling multiple instances o (c)tk.(C)Tk (in my case, in the main window and setup window classes). After adapting the setup window to a tk.Toplevel, the issue subsided. Thanks for your help.

Comment: post your answer.